# What should be the distance between plant promoter and gene?

Tags: botany, cloning, biotechnology

I am trying to clone a rice gene under a different endogenous rice promoter.I will be cloning the CDS of the rice gene.So I wanted to know what is the minimum or maximum distance I should put between the rice and the promoter so that I can get good expression levels.

Should I check the expression of the construct in E.coli before transforming it?

What should steps should I follow before finally transforming the construct into rice?

Comment: where do you want to express the protein?

Comment: I will be overexpressing the protein in rice.